# generate an artificial data set for context bandit algorithm

Tags: python, bandit-python

I want to generate the following artificial dataset to test a contextual bandit algorithm. What is the easiest way to get it done in python may be? Can anyone point me to a link which demonstrates a code for it?

The unit vectors θ1 , ..., θK for K actions are drawn uniformly from Rd . in each iteration t of T complete iterations, a context xt is first sampled from an uniform distribution within ∥x| ≤ 1.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question right, you want to generate:

1. context xt from uniform distribution
2. a unit vector of K elements indicating which arm to choose with only a single value being set to one, again from a uniform distribution

Both tasks can be easily achieved with the numpy package:

1. Use [numpy.random.uniform](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.random.uniform.html) to generate values from uniform distribution within any range.
2. Use [numpy.random.randint](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.random.randint.html#numpy.random.randint) to generate integers from uniform distribution and then use the generated values to set certain list element to 1.

Comment: would this kind of sampling ensure that the l2-norm of the context vector x is less than or equal to 1?